# Prevent hard drive from powering on when resuming from suspend to RAM

Tags: mount, hard-disk, disk, power-management, suspend

My laptop running Debian testing (Bullseye) has two hard drives: the first with the OS and my documents, and the second containing data that I use rarely. There is no link between these two drives (no RAID, no LVM). I would like the second hard drive to stay off except when I manually mount it, so I added the `noauto` option to `/etc/fstab`.

However, while the drive is not mounted and is powered off before suspending to RAM, it keeps powering on each time my laptop resume.

Is it possible to tell Linux/udev to not power on that drive automatically on resume?

Comment: I have not used these, and it may want to check drive on resume. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Automount_with_systemd & 
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/systemd/systemd.automount.5.en.html
Either systemd-automount or autofs can be used. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Comment: I do not need automatic mounting, I just need my drive not to spin up automatically on resume.